# How do I use `render_template` from Flask in Angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, python-3.x, flask

What I'm trying to accomplish is different routes for the different Angular Material tabs. I've tried calling `Flask` right from the template, as shown below, and I seem to be unable to call `render_template` from Angular. I've also tried escaping the `{{ [stuff] }}` to `{{ "{{ [stuff] }}" }}` Is there a way to do this that I haven't found? The affected code is:

```
$stateProvider
.state("dashboard", { abtract: true, url:"/dash", templateUrl: {{ render_template('partials/tabs/Dashboard.html') }} })
.state("dashboard.commands", { url: "/dash/commands", templateUrl: {{ render_template('partials/tabs/Commands.html') }} })
.state("dashboard.support", { url: "/dash/support", templateUrl: {{ render_template('partials/tabs/Support.html') }} })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't call a server-side function inside your AngluarJs script. Servers' API only work through GET/POST request on given URLs. `templateUrl` should probably just be an url, such as `'partials/tabs/Support.html'` and *then* the Flask server, when being asked for the page, renders the template.

That, or I missed your request, in which case more detail is welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using flask's [`url_for`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.11/api/#flask.url_for) method? It automatically generates correct URLs according to corresponding view functions. So what you probably need is the following:

```
$stateProvider
.state("dashboard", { abtract: true, url:"/dash", templateUrl: {{ url_for('show_dashboard') }} })
.state("dashboard.commands", { url: "/dash/commands", templateUrl: {{ url_for('show_commands') }} })
.state("dashboard.support", { url: "/dash/support", templateUrl: {{ url_for('show_support') }} })
```

In your views (`views.py` or whatever) you define these functions like that:

```
@app.route('/partials/tabs/Dashboard.html')
def show_dashboard():
    render_template('partials/tabs/Dashboard.html')

@app.route('/partials/tabs/Commands.html')
    def show_commands():
        render_template('partials/tabs/Commands.html')

@app.route('/partials/tabs/Support.html')
    def show_support():
        render_template('partials/tabs/Support.html')
```

etc.